# Edit EditText in Fragment from MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent, bundle

I've tried to replace textviews whose are connected to fragment with data that I get from service. But even if I use LayoutInflator in Activity to edit those edittextes, I couldn't change them. All I understand is that I need to change them from the fragment but I need to send data from activity to fragment for that, which I couldn't achieve again.

Here's the code lines that I wrote inside **onCreate** of **MainActivity**

```
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View mView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_designreservation, null);

        Bundle extrasofuser = getIntent().getExtras();
        nameofuser = extrasofuser.getString("nameofuser").toString();
        surnameofuser = extrasofuser.getString("surnameofuser").toString();

        EditText enum_of_name = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.et_name);
        EditText enum_of_surname = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.et_surname);

        enum_of_name.setText(nameofuser);
        enum_of_surname.setText(surnameofuser);
```

As far as I know, I need to send those string variables to fragment but I couldn't do it. Thanks for your helps!!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well your problem, you need to set the text of a editText in a Fragment from your Activity. 
An approach is to keep a reference of the fragment in your activity.

```
     private MyFragment mFragment;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        mFragment = new MyFragment();
        ...
     }
```

And then create a method in your fragment class to change the EditText text:

```
     public void changeEditTextContent(Bundle extras){
          String nameofuser = extrasofuser.getString("nameofuser").toString();
          String surnameofuser = extrasofuser.getString("surnameofuser").toString();

           EditText enum_of_name = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.et_name);
           EditText enum_of_surname = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.et_surname);

           enum_of_name.setText(nameofuser);
           enum_of_surname.setText(surnameofuser);
     }
```

Lastly, from your activity you can call this method:

```
     Bundle extrasofuser = getIntent().getExtras();
     mFragment.changeEditTextContent(extrasofuser);
```

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly but I still get error which say ---- "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference" -----

Comment: That's because it is not finding the EditTexts in your layout.  Are those editText in the Activity or in the fragment? It would be nice if you can post your Activity and fragment code

Comment: My fragment is now at default mode. I haven't writed anything there yet. I've tried to change them from activity and the code lines I added on the question are from MainActivity already. I know I need to change EditTextes from Fragment but the problem is I couldn't send any data from activity to fragment.

Comment: You have to code your fragment. Like I wrote it should work, or if you have the data needed before showing the fragment you can use a Bundle to send it as an Extra, but you have to code the fragment to receive it